# How can I embed ytpak video in my html page using iframe?

Tags: html, iframe

How can I embed `ytpak` (https://www.ytpak.pk/) video in my html page using `iframe`?

iframe easily embed youtube video my html page but it cannot embed ytpak video?

Also I cannot find the proper documentation regarding instruction on how to do it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>YTpak Video </title>
</head>

<body>
    <iframe src="https://www.ytpak.pk/watch?v=JFcgOboQZ08"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

This code cannot work for embedding ytpak videos,

Comment: what is ytpak, a service? Have you checked their documentation?

Comment: https://www.ytpak.pk/

Comment: ytpak is website like youtube but it's specific for pakistan when youtube is blocked in pakistan

Comment: What their documentation says about embedding video?

Comment: i can not find their documentation so i put my question here ? if you find kindly tell me?

Comment: sorry, I cannot access this site from where I am. Just tried to give a headsup in the good direction